# CakePHP 2.1 enters infinite loop when saving a record

Tags: cakephp, save, cakephp-2.1

The question probably sounds quite odd, and indeed it is. Here's the problem: I have a model, `FollowingStationLine`, and its corresponding table, `following_station_lines`. In the model, I am trying to save a record with `$this->save(array('field' => 'value));`. When I hit the corresponding page, the method seems to be calling in an infinite loop (I've put some `debug()`s before and after the save statement) and it ends only when the memory limit has been reached. I tried even with 2GB of memory, and still the same issue.

This happens also when calling the method from another controller, other than `FollowingStationLinesController`. All other models/tables work as expected, beside this one. I really can't imagine what is the problem. Here are the codes for the controller, respectively the model:

Controller:

```
    App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

    class FollowingStationLinesController extends AppController {

    public function admin_set() {
        $this->FollowingStationLine->set(array(1));
    }

}
```

Model:

```
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class FollowingStationLine extends AppModel {
    public function set($lineIds = array()){
        if(!is_array($lineIds)){
            return false;   
        }
        $save = array();
        $save[] = array('station_id' => 45);
        debug($save[0]);
        $this->save($save[0]);
    }
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CakePHP's AppModel class has a function called 'set' that is called by the model's 'save' function.  By overrriding 'set', you are causing a loop between the 2 methods.

Rename your function to something else and you should be ok.

You can inspect the AppModel source for more info:  https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php

---

***UPDATE:***

@mark made a very good comment that if your PHP configuration included error reporting mode E_STRICT,  you would have received an error for overriding with a mismatched signature.

More info to set your configuration:  http://php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php

Comment: Oh my...very frustrating, been stuck for a couple of days on this...Thank you for this precious hint. Didn't realize I was overriding Cake's method.

Comment: @linkyndy When in doubt, go to the source!  :)

Comment: Know, but missed the possibility of overriding a method. Lesson learnt :)

Comment: Tip: developing in E_STRICT mode would have thrown an error here (as you override methods with a different set of params here)